# directed graph edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

From what I understand, the shortest path would be from 7 to 15 is:

7-->10-->14-->13-->15

From this assumption, there are five nodes. How many edges would there be in the shortest path?

Does the formula $n * (n-1)$ still holds? If, so there would be 20, but I am having a hard time seeing that many edges.

Comment: How many edges or paths ?

Comment: I am looking for edges

Comment: 5 nodes, then 4 edges ?

Comment: SO is the formula above for paths?

Answer (score 1):

There are four edges in your path. The edge from 7 to 10, the edge from 10 to 14, the edge from 14 to 13, and the edge from 13 to 15.

$n * (n-1)/2$ is the number of edges in a complete graph on $n$ vertices. A path with $n$ vertices always has $n-1$ edges.